# Easiest way to create a complex xml File out of a Object

Tags: java, xml

What's the best option to create a complex xml-file out of an object? Root file has up too 6 childs, with a lot of entries. Which tags have a values asinged can vary between different files.

```
<root>
<child>
    <Child>
        <child>
            <child</child>
```

StaX, DOMParser or using a template.

Comment: That depends on your definition of "easiest".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB) API in order to do that.
I wrote simple employee class to explain how to achieve it by using JAXB.

```
/*Employee class as root node*/
@XmlRootElement
public class Employee {

private String name;
private int age;
private int id;
private double salary;

public Employee() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Employee(String name, int age, int id, double salary) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.id = id;
    this.salary = salary;
}

/*add as attribute into root node*/
@XmlAttribute
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/*add as element*/
@XmlElement
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

@XmlAttribute
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@XmlElement
public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

}
```

In main method you can write this employee object data into xml file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException,
        FileNotFoundException {

    JAXBContext contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);

    Marshaller marshallerObj = contextObj.createMarshaller();
    marshallerObj.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    Employee emp1 = new Employee("saman", 23, 001, 2500.00);

    marshallerObj.marshal(emp1, new FileOutputStream("employee.xml"));

}
```

The employee.xml file like this :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <employee id="1" name="saman">
    <age>23</age>
    <salary>2500.0</salary>
   </employee>
```

So you can use annotations to java objects in order to build your xml file. format.

Answer (score 0):

I like to pass stuff like this to the object itself.

You could write an interface like:

```
public interface XMLWriteable {

   /** Write stuff to XML file **/
   public void writeXML( PrintWriter pWriter );
}
```

And in your Class:

```
public class Object2XML implements XMLWriteable{
  ...
  public void writeXML( PrintWriter pWriter ){
    pWriter.println("<ObjectTag>");
    //Write Some values
    pWriter.println("<stringTag>"+value+"</stringTag>");
    //Write other complex XMLWriteable Objects
    XMLWObj.writeXML(pWriter);
    //Close your tag
    pWriter.println("</ObjectTag>");
  }
 }
```

And then it is easy to save the Object.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Object2XML obj = new Object2XML();
  //Do something with the Object
  //Save Object
  obj.writeXML(new PrintWriter("your/xml/file"));
}
```

This is one possible way. Hope I helped.